# Regex, how can I grab just the first line of output?

Tags: regex, unix

My output has more than 1 line, so I am trying to match the linebreak at the end of the line and then have only 1 max occurance. I was trying something like this: `^$output*\n$\{,1\}` but that didn't really work out right.

Comment: Good question, silly me. Unix.

Comment: @Brian Why didn't I think of that? Dammit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab the first line of output using the Unix utility `head`

`head -1`

Answer (score 2):

What language?  In sed:  `sed -e 's/:/!/g' -e '1q' /etc/passwd`  The second command means "quit on line 1".

In perl you can use the `m` flag to treat one long, multi-line string as multiple lines and then `$` will match the first newline.

In awk you could either make the line number part of the condition: `awk '/.../ && NR == 1 { print }'` or you could quit after the first line:  `awk '/.../ { print } { exit }'`

With grep you could limit the file with head:  `head -1 file | grep pattern` or limit to the first *matching* line with `grep -c 1 pattern file...`

Comment: sed is an entire language, each `-e` is like a line in a script.  You could also put them in a file and use `-f file`.  sed even has blocks and looping.